# check if look up edit is selected

Tags: c#, devexpress

Here is code that i used to populate a look up edit:

```
Letsap.DAL.PersonDataSet dsPerson = new Letsap.DAL.PersonDataSet();

lookUpEdit3.Properties.DataSource = dsPerson.GetPersonsID();
lookUpEdit3.Properties.ValueMember = "Person_ID";
lookUpEdit3.Properties.DisplayMember = "Person_Name";
lookUpEdit3.EditValue = 0;
```

But I would like to check if the user selected a value, if they did, it must move on to the next screen.

How do I do the check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this. Assuming you have a button with a click event attached, on which you want to check wheter you want to continue:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (lookUpEdit3.ItemIndex >= 0)
  {
    // show next screen
  }
}
```

Comment: @user2721295 glad I could help ;-) you can after 15min